# Remove redundancy in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with sql query. I want to order the entries in the tables, so newer records come first. I used for it this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM swt_subjects
WHERE `type` = 2
ORDER BY `date_beg` DESC, `name` DESC
```

It works good in case if in table subject appears only once but in case if subject appears few times it is displayed in table multiply times. How I can modify this query to display each name only once?

The scheme of table in DB is:

```
id, name, type, date_beg, date_end
```

[image: displaying records from table - redundant record "Softwarepraktikum"]

Edit:
With GROUP BY it still doesn't display in correct way.
[image: Display with GROUP BY]

Comment: Perhaps using the SQL keyword [DISTINCT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx)

Comment: Why does the table contain multiple records for a single subject?

Comment: It contains multiple records because of existence in semesters, some subject are periodicall, some appears only once

Comment: But then, if you only want to display a subject once, for which semester do you want to obtain each subject's record?

Comment: Problem was about displaying this "x" with link to each semester of given subject, it should display subject ones but multiple information about this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT
  id, name, type, MAX(date_beg) as start, MAX(date_end) as end
FROM
  swt_subjects
WHERE
  type = 2
GROUP BY
  id, name, type
ORDER BY 
  start DESC, name DESC
```